# MouseEvents are Captured but not KeyEvents Java JComponant

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jcomponent, key-events

I'm working on an old game project called Lemmings, and the Principle Game Panel is working well and receiving the MouseEvents but not the KeyEvents, which is not very logic for me, so I copied down the Code of this file for you guys to see whats going on.

The GamePanel class extends JComponent SWING class

```
public class GameFrame {

private class GamePanel extends JComponent {

    GamePanel(Dimension dim) {

        setPreferredSize(dim);

         //first version of the question was with the keyListner
        /*addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);
                System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
                //nothing show up
            }
        });*/

         //I tried using this, but it didn't work
        //getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "action");

         // this works cause we use the right inputMap not the one by default 
         getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "action");
         getActionMap().put("action",new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("A is pressed");
                //now it works
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.println(e.getPoint());
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

private JFrame window;
private GamePanel panel; 

public GameFrame() {
    window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel = new GamePanel(new Dimension(400, 400));
    window.setContentPane(panel);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameFrame();
}
}
```

### UPDATE WITH SOLUTION

- I learned that JComponants are not focusable and so it doesn't receive KeyEvents so we have to use the Key Bindings method
- I found out that every JComponent has three inputMaps referred to by WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, WHEN_FOCUSED, WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT and we have to make sure that we are using the right one for our work
- for more informations look on [How to use key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and check the methods **getInputMap()** and **getInputMap(int)**

Comment: Include your code in your question.  If your project ever moves or goes away, this question, as it currently is, will be useless to future readers.

Comment: @VGR okay I will update the question so code can stay here

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Your question is about a KeyStroke on a panel. So all you need is a JFrame with a JPanel. That is about 5 lines of code. Then you need to create your Key Binding so you need to create an Action and a KeyStroke and to the binding. Another 10 lines of code. So the total code with be less than 20 lines of code in a single class the we can easily read or copy/paste/compile and test if we wish.

Comment: @camickr I've updated the question to have less code and more understandable question

Comment: It is not an [mcve]. 1) It should be in a single source file so we can copy/paste/compile/test. 2) There is no need for an enum. You are just trying to test out a concept so keep the logic simple. 3) There is no need for a custom "game component". Again the concept you are trying to learn is adding Key Bindings to a panel. Get the basic concept working with JDK components before creating custom components. Its easier to debug. 4) you didn't listen to my comment about using the proper InputMap. 5) did you also search the forum for examples the use an InputMap/ActionMap?

Comment: @camickr I have tried to minimize the code to be in one file as you said, and I hope it doesn't bother you that I didn't understand the concept of inputMaps from the first try, I did read more about them and I found out that there are indeed three referred to by WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, WHEN_FOCUSED, WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT and I used this new informations and it finally worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem can be solved simply by adding a KeyListener to the JFrame in case we don't need to create Actions and stuff

this solution can only be possible if there are no other components focusable.

in the file GameFrame.java 
in the function void init();
add

```
window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            System.out.println("test "+e.getKeyChar());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Only works is there is no other focusable component on the frame. Using a KeyListener is not the Swing solution since the Key Bindings API is newer for Swing and more flexible. A KeyListener is used in AWT because there is no other option.

Comment: @camickr Okay, I'' keep that in mind and add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Key events are only dispatch to a focusable component.

By default a JPanel is not focusable so it does not receive key events.

If you are attempting to invoke some kind of `Action` based on a KeyEvent then you should be using `Key Bindings`, not a KeyListener. A key binding will allow you to listen for a `KeyStroke` even if the component doesn't have focus.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I'm wondering why the MouseListener works but not the KeyListener ? days ago I had the same code and it used to work, but now it doesn't so I don't know what have changed

Comment: And I don't really want to Invoke an action or create a new action, when the button is clicked, I just want to send the key value to another class

Comment: I have used the Key Bindings but still not working, check the Gist I have updated it and the question as well

Comment: @SafiyZaghbane, `I'm wondering why the MouseListener works but not the KeyListener ?` - already answered in my first sentence. `...when the button is clicked,` what do clicking a button and typing a character have to do with one another? `I have used the Key Bindings but still not working,` - there are 3 InputMaps. You are using the default one which only works when the component has focus, which it doesn't. Try the other InputMaps.